# How to use SQLAlchemy TypeDecorators to compile raw SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a SqlAlchemy Query object that uses a `uuid.UUID`:

```
import uuid
import sqlalchemy

foreign_uuid = '822965bb-c67e-47ee-ad12-a3b060ef79ae'
qry = Query(MyModel).filter(MyOtherModel.uuid == uuid.UUID(foreign_uuid))
```

Now I want to get the raw postgresql from SQLAlchemy:

```
qry.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```

Which gives the following error: `NotImplementedError: Don't know how to literal-quote value UUID('822965bb-c67e-47ee-ad12-a3b060ef79ae')`

This seems to be because SqlAlchemy only knows how to deal with basic types.  [The documentation suggests](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type) to use a `TypeDecorator` and even provides one for GUIDs:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

class GUID(TypeDecorator):
    """Platform-independent GUID type.

    Uses PostgreSQL's UUID type, otherwise uses
    CHAR(32), storing as stringified hex values.

    """
    impl = CHAR

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(UUID())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(CHAR(32))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        elif dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return str(value)
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                return "%.32x" % uuid.UUID(value).int
            else:
                # hexstring
                return "%.32x" % value.int

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                value = uuid.UUID(value)
            return value
```

However it doesn't say how to *use* this `TypeDecorator`.  Do I need to reference it somehow in my model?  Do I make it available somehow to the `.statement.compile` call?

Comment: `Do I need to reference it somehow in my model?` Yes. It is to be used as the type for your column `Column('uuid', GUID)`. Another option would be to skip that `uuid.UUID` instantiation and pass the `foreign_uuid` string directly to a `CHAR` column `qry = Query(MyModel).filter(MyOtherModel.uuid == foreign_uuid)` - if you don't really need it to be a `UUID` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can sqlalchemy work with custom class as the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257478/how-can-sqlalchemy-work-with-custom-class-as-the-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

You use the decorated type as your column type.  Another set of docs explains it a little more clearly: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#faq-sql-expression-string

```
   from sqlalchemy import TypeDecorator, Integer

 
   class MyFancyType(TypeDecorator):
       impl = Integer

       def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
           return "my_fancy_formatting(%s)" % value

   from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, MetaData

      tab = Table('mytable', MetaData(), Column('x', MyFancyType()))
```